# How to download all files from a specific Sourceforge project?

Tags: wget, sourceforge, msys

After spending about an hour downloading almost every Msys package from sourceforge I'm wondering whether there is a more clever way to do this. Is it possible to use wget for this purpose?

Comment: Well, I could but Msys does not offer SVN/Git access, do they?

Answer (score 8):

I've used this script successfully:

https://github.com/SpiritQuaddicted/sourceforge-file-download

For your use run:

```
sourceforge-file-downloader.sh msys
```

It should download all the pages first then find the actual links in the pages and download the final files.

From the project description:

> Allows you to download all of a sourceforge project's files. Downloads to the current directory into a directory named like the project. Pass the project's name as first argument, eg ./sourceforge-file-download.sh inkscape to download all of http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape/files/

Just in case the repo ever gets removed I'll post it here since it's short enough:

```
#!/bin/sh

project=$1
echo "Downloading $project's files"

# download all the pages on which direct download links are
# be nice, sleep a second
wget -w 1 -np -m -A download http://sourceforge.net/projects/$project/files/

# extract those links
grep -Rh direct-download sourceforge.net/ | grep -Eo '".*" ' | sed 's/"//g' > urllist

# remove temporary files, unless you want to keep them for some reason
rm -r sourceforge.net/

# download each of the extracted URLs, put into $projectname/
while read url; do wget --content-disposition -x -nH --cut-dirs=1 "${url}"; done < urllist

rm urllist
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of no wget or shell install do it with FileZilla: sftp://yourname@web.sourceforge.net you open the connection with sftp and your password then you browse to the /home/pfs/

after that path (could be a ? mark sign) you fill in with your folder path you want to download in remote site, in my case
**/home/pfs/project/maxbox/Examples/**

this is the access path of the frs: File Release System: /home/frs/project/PROJECTNAME/
[image: filezilla_sourceforge]

Comment: missing information, maybe? I don't have FileZilla, but I tried to use CoreFTP-LE with sftp and the information provided above and get:
dh-group1-sha1 not specified
crypto error, disconnecting...
SFTP connection error

Comment: did you get a HOST-Key for SFTP, in filezilla you can check better your credentials

Comment: Note: your project directory (/home/frs/project/fooproject) is available, even if you cannot see it listed!

Comment: Thats what breitsch says, you can navigate to your path without seeing it in filezilla, just type it at the remote path.