# Download whole folder from SourceForge

Tags: download, directory, sourceforge

I need to download a project from SourceForge, but there is no easy visible way. 
Here, on this picture (linked down, not enough reputation), it is possible to download "the latest version", which does include only files from first folder, but I need to download other folder.

It is possible to download these files, but only manually and because there are hundreds of files and subfolders - it would be quite impractical.

Does anyone know any way to download it? I didn't find much, only some mentioned wget, but I tried it without any success.

Link: http://s9.postimg.org/xk2upvbwv/example.jpg

Comment: One reason why SourceForge almost died: poor UX.

Comment: similar question: [How to download all files from a specific Sourceforge project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390379/how-to-download-all-files-from-a-specific-sourceforge-project)

Answer (score 19):

In every Sourceforge project or project folders page there is an RSS link, as you can see in the [example screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqsnH.jpg).

right click that RSS icon in the page of the folder or project you want to download then copy the link and use the following Bash script:

```
curl "<URL>" | grep "<link>.*</link>" | sed 's|<link>||;s|</link>||' | while read url; do url=`echo $url | sed 's|/download$||'`; wget $url ; done
```

replace "<URL>" with your RSS link for example : "https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdxf/rss?path=/dicts-babylon/001", and watch the magic happens, The RSS link will include all the files of the Sourceforge folder or project and it's sub-folders, so the script will download everything recursively.

If the above script doesn't work, try this one that extracts the links from the HTML directly, Replace "<URL>" with the project's files URL example : "https://sourceforge.net/projects/synwrite-addons/files/Lexers/"

```
curl "<URL>" | tr '"' "\n" | grep "sourceforge.net/projects/.*/download"  | sort  | uniq | while read url; do url=`echo $url | sed 's|/download$||'`; wget $url ; done
```

Good luck

Comment: Using this will take some time to download but in my case, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: This is a working solution, however, I use this method and try to download for example, https://sourceforge.net/projects/synwrite-addons/files/Lexers/       It does not download all the files in the folder. There are 298 items in the sourceforge folder, however using this command I only downloaded 101 items.

Comment: You are right CRquantum, for some reason the RSS of sourceforge.net only has a 100 entries, it seems there is a limit for the number items that can be included, I just added another script that extracts the links directly from Web page HTML and download the files.

Comment: i tried to brute-force a pagination parameter for the rss url, but no luck. ideally, sourceforge would provide a paginated api to list all files

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes there is a download link at the summary tab, but sometimes I don't know a work around so I use this piece of code:

```
var urls = document.getElementsByClassName('name')
var txt = ""
for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  txt += "wget " + urls[i].href +"\n"
}
alert(txt)
```

You should open a console in your browser on the page where all the files are listed. Copy+past+enter the code and you will be prompted a list of `wget` commands which you can Copy+past+enter in your terminal.

Comment: On me, file saved with  name "download" "download.1" "download.2" etc.
In this case use the "--content-disposition" option to save with the original filename.
Awesome solution!

Comment: This is a very clever solution, but I'd suggest removing the `wget` before each URL to make it possible to copy-paste all the links directly into a file that can then be used with `wget -i`. Otherwise, if I've understood correctly, you'd have to copy-paste each `wget + URL` into the console, which would be even more impractical than individually downloading them from the website.

Answer (score 2):

### How to download all files from a particular folder in Sourceforge on Windows 10:

Step 1: Download the latest wget (zip file, not exe file) from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/.

Note: Search google for 'wget 1.20.x' to find proper link, if necessary. Download the 32-bit file, if your system is Winodws 10 32-bit or the 64-bit file, if your system is Windows 10 64-bit.

Step 2: Download the latest grep and coreutils installers from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html.

Note: Search google for 'gnuwin32' to find proper link, if necessary. Only the 32-bit installers are available.

Step 3: Extract everything in the wget zip file downloaded to C:\WgetWinx32 or C:\WgetWinx64.

Note: You can install the wget virtually anywhere but preferably in a folder without space in the folder name.

Step 4: Install grep by double-clicking the respective installer to a folder, C:\GnuWin32.

Step 5: Install coreutils by double-clicking the respective installer to the same folder where the grep has been installed.

Note: You can install the grep and the coreutils in any order you want (i.e., first grep and then coreutils or vice versa) and virtually anywhere, even in the default location shown by the installer, but preferably in a folder without space in the folder name.

Step 6: Right-click on the 'This PC' icon in the desktop. Select the 'properties' menu from the drop-down list. Select the 'Advanced system settings' from the pop-up 'System' window.
        Select the 'Environment Variables...' from the pop-up 'System properties' window. Select 'Path' from the 'System variables' and click on the 'Edit...' button.
        Click on the 'New' button in the 'Edit environment variables' pop-up window. Enter the path for the wget installation folder (e.g., 'C:\WgetWin32' or 'C:\WgetWin64' without quotes).
        Click on the 'New' button in the 'Edit environment variables' pop-up window again. Enter the path for the grep and coreutils installation folder (e.g., 'C:\GnuWin32\bin' without quotes).
        Now, keep clicking on the 'Ok' buttons in the 'Edit environment variables', 'System variables' and 'System properties' pop-up windows.

Step 7: Create a DOS batch file, 'wgetcmd.bat' in the wget installation folder (e.g., 'C:\WgetWin32' or 'C:\WgetWin64' without quotes) with the following line using a text editor.

```
    cd C:\WgetWin32
    cmd
    (OR)
    cd C:\WgetWin64
    cmd
```

Step 8: Create a shortcut to this batch file on the desktop.

Step 9: Right-click on the shortcut and select the 'Run as administrator' from the drop-down list.

Step 10: Enter the following commands either one by one or all at once in the DOS prompt in the pop-up DOS command window.

```
    wget -w 1 -np -m -A download <link_to_sourceforge_folder>
    grep -Rh refresh sourceforge.net | grep -o "https[^\\?]*" > urllist
    wget -P <folder_where_you_want_files_to_be_downloaded> -i urllist
```

That's all folks! This will download all the files from the Sourceforge folder specified.

Answer (score 0):

Example for the above: Suppose that I want to download all the files from the Soruceforge folder: https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/, then the following lines of commands will do this.

```
wget -w 1 -np -m -A download https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/
grep -Rh refresh sourceforge.net | grep -o "https[^\\?]*" > urllist
wget -P OctaveForgePackages -i urllist
```

The Sourceforge folder mentioned above contains a lot of Octave packages as .tar.gz files. All those files would be downloaded to the folder 'OctaveForgePackages' locally!

Comment: This worked briliantly, thank you!

Comment: see also https://github.com/SpiritQuaddicted/sourceforge-file-download

Comment: problem: this is slow, because it downloads all the "download this file" pages

Answer (score 0):

In case of no wget or shell install do it with FileZilla:
sftp://yourname@web.sourceforge.net
you open the connection with sftp and your password then
you browse to the /home/pfs/

after that path (could be a ? mark sign) you fill in with your folder path you want to download in remote site, in my case
**/home/pfs/project/maxbox/Examples/**

this is the access path of the frs:
File Release System: /home/frs/project/PROJECTNAME/
[image: filezilla_sourceforge]

Comment: This does not seem to work. Perhaps could you give an example how to download the stuff in this folder  https://sourceforge.net/projects/synwrite-addons/files/Lexers/              Thanks much!

Comment: You should first export in sourceforge what you want:
https://sourceforge.net/p/maxbox/admin/export
Then you get email with instructions :
The following tools were exported:
- admin

Follow the instructions below to get your exported data.

To download your backup, run: scp maxkleiner@web.sourceforge.net:/home/project-exports/maxbox/maxbox-backup-2023-03-09-190248.zip .
Or, use sftp to connect to host "web.sourceforge.net" user "maxkleiner" and change directory to /home/project-exports/maxbox and download maxbox-backup-2023-03-09-190248.zip
This file will be available for 7 days.

Comment: Note: your project directory (/home/frs/project/fooproject) is available, even if you cannot see it listed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample Python script you could use to download from SourceForge:

```py
import os
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_files_from_sourceforge(sf_url, download_dir):

    r = requests.get(sf_url) 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    
    files = [file.a['href'] for file in soup.find_all('th', headers='files_name_h')]
        
    for file_download_url in files:
        filename = file_download_url.split('/')[-2]

        # Skip files that already exist
        if filename not in os.listdir(download_dir):
            r = requests.get(file_download_url)
    
            with open(os.path.join(download_dir, filename), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
                print(f"created file {os.path.join(download_dir, filename)}")


download_files_from_sourceforge('https://sourceforge.net/Files/filepath',
                                'your/download/directory/here')
```

Comment: Works fine with maXbox4 but each subdirectory must be step by step:
Exception: <class 'requests.exceptions.MissingSchema'>: Invalid URL '/projects/maxbox/files/Examples/ICT/ICT_Mod_321/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///projects/maxbox/files/Examples/ICT/ICT_Mod_321/?.

Answer (score 0):

some bash code to implement a recursive file downloader for sourceforge

im using `wget --no-clobber` to skip existing files, to make the downloader faster. this could be optimized further by skipping existing folders

the example code block will

- get a file list from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/
- filter the file list, so there is only one file per folder
- download the filtered file list to `downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sevenzip/7-Zip/`

when a sourceforge folder url is passed to the script, it will download all files

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# license: "public domain" or "MIT license"

debug=false
#debug=true

function sourceforge_get_file_urls() {

  # return one folder per line, multiple file urls per line

  local folder_url="$1"

  local html="$(curl -s "$folder_url")"

  local links="$(echo "$html" | grep '^<th scope="row" headers="files_name_h"><a href' | cut -d'"' -f6 | sed 's|^/|https://sourceforge.net/|')"

  $debug && echo "sourceforge_get_file_urls: links:" >&2
  $debug && echo "$links" | sed 's/^/  /' >&2

  # loop files
  # convert file urls to "proper basename" urls = locally resolve the first http redirect
  # example:
  # a: https://          sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/21.07/7z2107-src.tar.xz/download
  # b: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project /sevenzip      /7-Zip/21.07/7z2107-src.tar.xz
  $debug && echo "sourceforge_get_file_urls: looping files" >&2
  file_links=$(echo "$links" | grep '/download$')
  if [ -n "$file_links" ]; then
    echo "$file_links" |
    sed -E 's|^https://sourceforge.net/projects/([^/]+)/files/([^/]+)/(.*?)/download$|https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/\1/\2/\3|' |
    xargs echo -n
    echo
  fi

  # loop folders
  $debug && echo "sourceforge_get_file_urls: looping folders" >&2
  while read next_folder_url; do
    # recurse
    $debug && echo "sourceforge_get_file_urls: recurse from $folder_url to $next_folder_url" >&2
    sourceforge_get_file_urls "$next_folder_url"
  done < <(echo "$links" | grep '/$')
}



# generic: get url from args, download all files

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  exec sourceforge_get_file_urls "$1" |
  xargs -n1 wget --no-clobber --recursive --level=1
fi



# example: get only the 7z source tarballs from the sevenzip project

echo example: sourceforge_get_file_urls https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/ 7zip-files
sourceforge_get_file_urls https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/ 7zip-files |
while read folder_urls; do
  folder_urls=$(echo "$folder_urls" | tr ' ' $'\n')
  $debug && echo -e "folder_urls:\n$folder_urls"
  # pick only one file per folder
  file_url="$folder_urls"
  file_url=$(echo "$file_url" | grep -E '/7z[0-9]+(-src\.tar\.xz|-src\.7z|\.tar\.bz2)$')
  if [[ "$(echo "$file_url" | wc -l)" != 1 ]]; then
    # we still have multiple file urls
    # remove *.7z
    # example file urls:
    # https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sevenzip/7-Zip/22.01/7z2201-src.tar.xz
    # https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sevenzip/7-Zip/22.01/7z2201-src.7z
    file_url=$(echo "$file_url" | grep -E '/7z[0-9]+(-src\.tar\.xz|\.tar\.bz2)$')
  fi
  if [[ "$(echo "$file_url" | wc -l)" != 1 ]]; then
    # we still have multiple file urls
    echo "FIXME filter file urls:" >&2
    echo "$file_url" | sed 's/^/  /' >&2
  fi
  if [[ "$(echo "$file_url" | wc -l)" == 1 ]]; then
    $debug && echo "ok: $file_url" >&2
  fi
  echo "$file_url"
done |
xargs -n1 wget --no-clobber --recursive --level=1

# note: "wget --no-clobber" assumes that existing files are valid

# list all downloaded files, sort by version
echo "downloaded files:"
find downloads.sourceforge.net/ -type f | sort -V | sed 's/^/  /'
```